# IDE phpdoc type hints for properties with attributes

Tags: php, attributes, phpdoc, php-8

I'm working with PHP and I've encountered a challenge with IDE support for typed arrays. Here's a snippet of my code:

```php
<?php

class User extends BaseData
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $name,
        
        #[ArrayOf(Hobby::class)]
        public array $hobbies,
    ) {
    }
}
```

In this code, I'm using an attribute (#[ArrayOf(Hobby::class)]) to indicate that $hobbies is an array of Hobby objects. However, my IDE only recognizes $hobbies as a generic array, so I don't get any specific hints or autocompletion for Hobby objects.

To work around this, I added a PHPDoc comment:

```php
class User extends BaseData
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $name,

        #[ArrayOf(Hobby::class)]
        /** @var Hobby[] */
        public array $hobbies,
    ) {
    }
}
```

While this helps with IDE hints, I'm looking for a way to rely solely on attributes for IDE support, without having to use PHPDoc comments. Is there a way to adjust the PHPDoc in the attribute class itself, or another approach to achieve this?

Ideally, I'd like to find a solution that allows me to use attributes exclusively for specifying array types, to make my code cleaner and reduce the need for additional comments.

Any advice or suggestions on how to improve IDE recognition of typed arrays using attributes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you only using the attributes for IDE support, or do you actually use the attributes in the code? If it's only for IDE support, then stick to phpdoc only. Attributes enables you to add meta data to your classes/methods/properties that you can fetch at runtime using the Reflection API. It's not meant as an alternative to phpdoc and has a very different purpose. An attribute can have it's own arguments that aren't necessarily the same as the property, so the IDE can't use that as type hint for the property.